# Is there a Lagrangian whose Euler-Lagrange equation is the gradient?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I am trying to recast a problem I am working on in terms of Lagrangian mechanics.  I am in the following situation.  Suppose I have a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (a field).  In the its simplest case, I am studying constant functions. Since $X$ is an open ball, this is the same as studying:
$$ \nabla f = 0. $$

Embarrassing enough, I don't know how recast this simple differential equation in terms of Lagrangian mechanics.  Namely, I don't know which function $L(x,f, \nabla f)$ has the above as its Euler-Lagrangien equations.  More precisely, I think I cannot recast the problem as a Lagrangian over several variables but only one field.  Is there a standard way of doing this?

Perhaps more importantly: Else, is there a standard $L(x,f,\nabla f)$ whose solution is the constant functions?

Comment: But what is $x$? A real number?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a real number or vector with real entries.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In this answer we will rename the scalar field $f\equiv \phi$.

I) First we investigate if there is an action

$$\tag{1} S[\phi]~=~\int \! d^dx ~{\cal L}(x, \phi(x), \partial \phi(x), \partial^2 \phi(x), \ldots ) $$

such that the [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)

$$ \tag{2} E(x)~\equiv~\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)} $$

is the gradient of the field

$$ \tag{3} E(x) ~\stackrel{?}{=}~ \frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^i} ?$$

The first problem with eq. (3) is that the coordinate index $i$ on the rhs of eq. (3) does not match the lhs of eq. (3). It seems that the question is only meaningful in one dimension. So let us assume that $x$ is one dimensional. Then eq. (3) reads

$$ \tag{4} E(x) ~\stackrel{?}{=}~ \frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x} .$$

For consistency, we must demand that functional derivatives commute

$$ \tag{5} \frac{\delta E(x)}{\delta \phi(y)}~\stackrel{?}{=}~ (x \longleftrightarrow y). $$

However eq. (4) satisfies an **anticommutative** relation (6) instead:

$$ \tag{6} \frac{\delta E(x)}{\delta \phi(y)}~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\delta(x-y)~=~-(x \longleftrightarrow y). $$

So even in one dimension there is no action $S[\phi]$ with Euler-Lagrange operator (4).

II) If we are allowed to rewrite the eqs. of motion $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^i}= 0$ in equivalent forms, we could try to consider e.g.

$$ \tag{7} E(x) ~\stackrel{?}{=}~ (\partial \phi(x))^2 ,$$

which also makes sense for higher dimensional $x$ via a dot product. However, again it is straightforward exercise to check that the ansatz (7) does not meet the consistency condition (5).

Comment: Thank you, Qmechanic.  When I wrote: "More precisely, I think I cannot recast the problem as a Lagrangian over several variables but only one field"  it was for the same reason you constrained the problem to one dimension.  Would you know if we re-cast the problem as $L(x, \Phi, \nabla \Phi)$, where $\Phi$ is a vector there is a solution?  (For example, if $\Phi = \nabla f$.)  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your edited answer.  I think you solved it.  I can recast the problem as finding the critical points to
$$
I[ \Phi ] = \int L(x, \Phi, \nabla \Phi) dx, 
$$
where $L(x,\Phi , \nabla \Phi) = \sum_i \Phi_i^2 /2$, and where we restrict the background space to the set of vector valued functions $\Phi$ that are of the form $\Phi = \nabla f$, for some real valued function $f$.

Comment: @JJO: The situation changes completely if one is allowed to use Lagrange multipliers $\lambda^i$. Then e.g. the action $S[\phi, \lambda]=\int \!d^dx ~\lambda^i(x)~ \partial_i \phi(x)$ will produce the sought-for eqs. of motion.